# Preordering on a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am given a definition which states that a 'preodering on a set is a relation that is reflexive and transitive.'

Show that a relation $\leq$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$ by $z_1 \leq z_2$ iff $|z_1| = |z_2|$ is a preodering on $\mathbb{C}$.

I must be missing something here because clearly for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ we have $|z| = |z|$ and if $z_1 \leq z_2$ and $z_2 \leq z_3$ then that implies that $|z_1| = |z_2| = |z_3|$ which means that $z_1 \leq z_3$.  I must be reading the question wrong surely.  What am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything. Sometimes you get an easy problem.

Comment: Clearly, you just showed that $\leq$ defined above is a preordering on $\mathbb{C}$. Easy one:)

Comment: I honestly can not remember the last time I had an easy problem - hence my suspicion.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, as presented you have verified both reflexivity and transitivity for $\le$ on $\Bbb C$, and they follow from the same properties as in the equality relation itself. Sometimes it really just is that simple!

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*